# blank login screen for laptop with Intel 965 Express Chipset Family

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, login-screen

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04, current kernel is 3.5.0.02-generic.

I have downloaded and installed 2 days ago Intel Linux Graphics Installer deb file suitable for Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset Family. After one day, I can not boot in ubuntu, I have a black login screen. This should have generated my problems I suspect.

I have tried the following options in grub menu:

1. removing quiet and adding nomodeset options: stuck in the spash
   screen
2. remove splash & quiet: tty1
3. remove quiet: black screen
4. remove splash & quiet, add nomodeset: tty1
5. remove splash: black screen
6. replase splash with no splash: black screen
7. start old kernel (3.0.2.37): nothing

I have also tried `apt-get` -check, -update, -upgrde, -purge, -autoremove,... All no changes.

In recovery mode, I tried `dpkg` which resulted in no changes and start in graphics safe mode which stays in terminal.

Whenever I try to `startx` from terminal, I receive message

> X cannot stat /etc/X11/X

Is there any way to remove packages installed on 30th and 31/3/2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was the following in 3 steps:

1. reinstall xserver:

> sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
>
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

2... then run from recovery mode `dpkg`, 5 obsolete packages removed: x11-xfs-utils, libfs6, x11-apps, x11-session-utils, xinit.

3... I could login normally in graphics environment only as guest, so I had to login in tty and `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority`

Hope it helps someone else :)